# How to use loadercontext for splashScreenImage?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I understand that for air 3.6+, I MUST declare a loadercontext, may i know if I want a swf for mobile splash screen, how do i achieve it?

```
var loader:Loader= new Loader();
var lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
loader.load(new URLRequest("something.swf"),_lc);
```

after which in `splashScreenImage=""`, what should i put?

Comment: This is 2 questions - please move one to another question

Comment: oh, and dont use numbers for id's - that will cause you no end of problems

Comment: Hi Lee Burrows, thanks for your reply, I have split out the questions. Still looking for an answer

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a SWF as a SplashScreenImage, only an image.

Think about it - the splash page is displayed while the app loads. If you had a SWF as a splash page, you'd need a another splash page to display while your SWF splash page loaded, defeating the purpose of a splash screen.

Also, the image should be embedded, not loaded at runtime.